# Specifying columns that have to be ignored in the result data

Tags: sql, postgresql, dapper, postgresql-9.4

I have a *CTE* that returns the following table:

```
m_ids |gp_id |id |m_id |id |type|id |type|qty|...
------|------|---|-----|---|----|---|----|---|---
```

Columns `m_ids`, `gp_id` and `m_id` were used for join and have to be removed. The data then goes to the cliend side where Dapper will take care of ambiguity of column names, so that's not a problem.

The problem is how to remove certain columns from the data, because dapper will look on the order of columns in order to create entities.
I can't just select all required columns because of there's a lot of same names (and even if I could, that might be a bad idea because there is ***A LOT*** of columns that I need).

Can anyone help me with that?
The order of data have to be preserved, and in the end it should look something like that:

```
   id |id |type|id |type|qty|...
   ---|---|----|---|----|---|---
```

**EDIT:** The query that returns that data looks somewhat like this:

```
select
    m1.*,
    m2.*
from
    pairs p
    inner join materials m1 on m1.id=p.id1
    inner join materials m2 on m2.id=p.id2
```

Comment: Without seeing your original query, I won't attempt an answer.  Easiest way would be to just subquery your current query and alias the way you want.  Note that intermediate tables can't have two columns with the same alias, so `id` appearing three times won't fly; you'd have to alias them separately at first, then make the same in the outermost query.

Comment: Instead of selecting `m1.*` and `m2.*`, just select the columns you want to appear in the final result set, aliases added if necessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, I think that it might be the way to go. I just wanted to know if there is a way to actually ignore or drop columns with specified names in data that being returned.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/sql-select-all-columns-except-some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, when returning multiple entities in one row, Dapper uses the columns `id` as a delimiter, so the trick was to make sure that all the excessive columns are placed somewhere in the end of any entity, and Dapper will ignore it. So I put these columns in the order like that and that's it:

```
id |id |type|m_ids |gp_id |m_id |id |type|qty|...
---|---|----|------|------|-----|---|----|---|...
```